# API Powershell NSX-T

Tags: powershell, basic-authentication, vmware, invoke-webrequest

I would like to automate a new NAT in NSX-T,

I'd like to automate the addition of a new nat from an API with Powershell.

Except that I still have a "400".

Here's an example of my Powershell script:

```
username =
$password =

$body = @{   
   "display_name = ""
    "description" = ""
    "action" = "DNAT
    "destination_network" = ""
    "translated_network" = ""
    "translated_ports" = ""
    "sequence_number" = 0
    "enabled" = $true
    "logging" = $false
    "firewall_match" = ""
    "scope" = @()
    "_revision" = 0
} | ConvertTo-Json

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
    Content-Type'='application/json'
}

try {

    $results = Invoke-webrequest -uri "" -headers $headers -method patch -body $body 
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error : $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Host "HTTP error : $($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__)"
    Write-Host "Details : $($_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription)"
}
```

Comment: Leaving the syntax errors aside, there's no obvious problem with your code, and, without specifics, I suspect no one will be able to help you.